# Meteor: Template level subscription for looped templates OR when all subscriptions are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This is how I'm generating an article with an intro text and a list of elements, which are nested in multilevel. The main data (title, intro) is loaded by template level subscription. While loading the data, a spinner is shown. That's working so far.

Now I'm loading a nested list by using another template, which will be looped to get all needed data. The data is structured in a model tree structure with parent references. So for every loop, the children are loaded and added to the list. That means if the list goes three level deep, the template will be used three times.

My problems with that:

1. Every 'looping' will cause a new subscribe and find() request to get the elements of that level. Is it possible to do this another way to prevent multiple find()-requests?
2. Right now the list is loaded sequentially. But I would like to show a spinner until the complete list is loaded. But I can't use the same template level-subscription as used for the main data, because the template will be looped multiple times...
3. As I want to use some functions after the complete page is generated, I need to get the point when everything is finished (=removing spinner). For example if I want to add `autosize()` to all textareas shown in that list, it doesn't work if I do `Template.elements.onRendered(function(){ $('textarea').autosize(); });` as the last elements are not affected. I do not understand why.

**templates**

```
<template name="article">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}

        <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{article.intro}}</p>

        {{ > elements article._id }}

    {{else}}
        <div class="loading">{{ > spinner }}</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="elements">
    <ul>
    {{#each elements}}
        <li>
            <textarea>{{title}}</textarea>
            {{ > elements _id }}
        </li
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**helpers**

```
Template.article.helpers({
    article: function() { return Template.instance().article(); }
});

Template.elements.helpers({
    children: function(parentId) {
        Meteor.subscribe('elements', parentId); 
        return Collection.find({ parent: parentId }, { sort: { order: 1 } });
    }
});
```

**onCreated**

```
Template.article.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;

    instance.autorun(function () {
        var subscription = instance.subscribe('article', Session.get('docId'));
    });

    instance.article = function() { return Collection.findOne({ _id: Session.get('docId') }); };

});
```

**onRendered**

```
Template.elements.onRendered(function() {
    $('textarea').autosize();
});
```

This is how the data is structured in the DB:

```
{
    "_id" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "title" : "Article title",
    "intro" : "Some text",
    "type" : "section",
}
{
    "_id" : "eYkxs8rW3dKH5SfoE",
    "title" : "element 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "siaRPzaTgDrfWZ7kn",
    "title" : "subelement 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An"
}
{
    "_id" : "DrfWZ7knsiaRPzaTg",
    "title" : "subelement 2",
    "order" : 2,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An"
}
{
    "_id" : "XZF9hpW8ZqTnRdkEg",
    "title" : "element 2",
    "order" : 3,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An",
    "title" : "group 1",
    "type" : "group",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "order" : 2
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using two collections instead? You can store main collection ID and find the subs using that ID & show spinner until subscription is ready for the main doc and then it can show spinner for the sub docs until they're ready. You'll do two publish/subscribes but those two will be separated. Didn't understand if thats what you want though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, going down the list:

> 1. Every 'looping' will cause a new subscribe and find() request to get the elements of that level. Is it possible to do this another way to prevent multiple find()-requests?

Yes. I would make a slight modification to your **data schema** and include the top-level parent ID on each sub-document:

```
{
    "_id" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "title" : "Article title",
    "intro" : "Some text",
    "type" : "section",
}
{
    "_id" : "eYkxs8rW3dKH5SfoE",
    "title" : "element 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "immediateParent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "topLevelParent": "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "siaRPzaTgDrfWZ7kn",
    "title" : "subelement 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "immediateParent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An",
    "topLevelParent": "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "DrfWZ7knsiaRPzaTg",
    "title" : "subelement 2",
    "order" : 2,
    "type" : "element",
    "immediateParent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An",
    "topLevelParent": "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "XZF9hpW8ZqTnRdkEg",
    "title" : "element 2",
    "order" : 3,
    "type" : "element",
    "immediateParent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "topLevelParent": "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An",
    "title" : "group 1",
    "type" : "group",
    "order" : 2,
    "immediateParent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "topLevelParent": "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
```

Now each document has access to its top-level parent element. Your **publish function** would then be:

```
Meteor.publish( 'articles', function( articleId ) {
  return Collection.find({ $or: [ {_id: articleId }, { topLevelParent: articleId }] };
});
```

And your article **onCreated** function would look like:

```
Template.article.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;

    instance.autorun(function () {
        var subscription = instance.subscribe('articles', Session.get('docId'));
    });
    instance.article = function() { return Collection.findOne({ _id: Session.get('docId') }); };
});
```

Your templates will be modified slightly:

```
<template name="article">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}

        <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{article.intro}}</p>

        {{> elements articleId=article._id }}

    {{else}}
        <div class="loading">{{ > spinner }}</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="elements">
    <ul>
    {{#each elements articleId}}
        <li>
            <textarea>{{title}}</textarea>
            {{> elements articleId=_id }}
        </li
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Just making sure everything passes through to the child templates here.  I'm passing the articleId down to each child template.

On the helpers side, you'll need to add an elements helper to your elements template:

```
Template.elements.helpers({
    elements: function( articleId ) {
        return Collection.find({ parent: articleId }, { sort: { order: 1 });
    }
});
```

Now you should be getting all needed data in the one publication and subscription. Your second question:

> 2. Right now the list is loaded sequentially. But I would like to show a spinner until the complete list is loaded. But I can't use the same template level-subscription as used for the main data, because the template will be looped multiple times...

Since all data for all sub-templates is available on the first Template.subscriptionsReady, I think you'll find this is no longer a problem.

> 3. As I want to use some functions after the complete page is generated, I need to get the point when everything is finished (=removing spinner). For example if I want to add autosize() to all textareas shown in that list, it doesn't work if I do Template.elements.onRendered(function(){ $('textarea').autosize(); }); as the last elements are not affected. I do not understand why.

This one is a bit of a stinker since the elements are being dynamically loaded into the DOM. Ugly, but I'd probably modify your subscription call to execute the autosize after a timeout:

```
var subscription = instance.subscribe('articles', Session.get('docId'), function() {
  Meteor.setTimeout( function() { $('textarea').autosize(); }, 500); // Adjust down to a lower amount if possible.
});
```

Hope that works!

Comment: That sounds great. How can I get a little function to add the toplevelparent info to the existing data? I think I have to do an each-loop for every element, right?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to loop through each item, and iterate up through the parents of that item until you find the top-level one, then set it.

Answer (score -1):

You can subscribe to the publication anywhere you want on the page, so you can put your subscribe in the parent template onCreated or onRendered.

You pass `article._id` to your child template, then use that `parentId` in the element template.

You know the article._id in the article template, so you can subscribe to the child template data in that template onCreated or onRendered.

If this is not what you are doing, please clarify your question: in your template `element` is the template nested inside `article`

If you want the full list of `elements`, you can subscribe to this list, and you'll get all `elements`. Then the collection is already loaded so it's cheap to lookup a single `element` in the `article` template because it will be done on the client only.

Comment: But I can't do that as I don't know the IDs of the elements before I do the loop.

Comment: edited my answer. Or you should edit you question because in my understanding of it you can do it.
PS: if you want help, don't downvote people who attempt to answer your question.

Comment: I added the data structure to the question. So I don't think I can get a full list of all elements, as they are just referenced by parent...

Comment: So, you do have the parent ID in the 'section' part. So in your parent template you can subscribe to all 'elements' that have that parent. Not sure why you say you can't.